# Jackson - serialize to other than string

Tags: string, serialization, enums, jackson

I am new here and this is my first post. I recently got into touch with Jackson and i would like to know if it's possible to get other values than string (or int) while serializing. Pleae be kind if I confuse parts of the terminus.

For example: I have enum

```
 public static enum Type {A, B, C}
```

in a class like

```
public class MyClass{
   private Type charCat;
   public Type getCharCat(){
      return this.charCat;
   }
   public void setCharCat(Type t){
      this.charCat = t;
   }
}
```

But if I create an Object (for example with charCat A) and write it into a file I get

> ...
>   charCat: "A"
>   ...

How could i get

> ...
>   charCat: A
>   ...

?

I tried several tips and solutions, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking for, but the only valid kind of JSON would be

```
{ "charCat" : "A" }
```

as all textual values MUST be enclosed in double-quotes. Only values that do not need that are numbers, boolean values (`true` and `false`) and `null`. So serializing value as

```
{ charCat : A }
```

would not be valid JSON; so there is no way to get such output.